# How do you concatenate two strings in a for loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I didn't explain very well the first time. I'll try again.

I want to simplify these if statements with a for loop. CatagoryX is (1-3) so I thought I could cycle through the variable, but I don't know how to write the code.

I want to simplify this with a for loop.

```
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, catagory1, catagory2, catagory3 FROM listofbooks;
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

//check to see if catagory1 is an 18, 19, or 20, and make $bookcatagory=the name
if (catagory1 == "18"){
    $bookcatagory == "Thriller";
    catagory1 = "";
}

if (catagory1 == "19"){
    $bookcatagory == "Fantasy";
    catagory1 = "";
}

if (catagory1 == "20"){
    $bookcatagory == "Science Fiction";
    catagory1 = "";
}

//check to see if catagory2 is an 18, 19, or 20, and make $bookcatagory=the name

if (catagory2 == "18"){
    $bookcatagory2 == "Thriller";
    catagory2 = "";
}

if (catagory2 == "19"){
    $bookcatagory2 == "Fantasy";
    catagory2 = "";
}

if (catagory2 == "20"){
    $bookcatagory2 == "Science Fiction";
    catagory2 = "";
}

//check to see if catagory2 is an 18, 19, or 20, and make $bookcatagory=the name

if (catagory3 == "18"){
    $bookcatagory2 == "Thriller";
    catagory3 = "";
}

if (catagory3 == "19"){
    $bookcatagory2 == "Fantasy";
    catagory3 = "";
}

if (catagory3 == "20"){
    $bookcatagory2 == "Science Fiction";
    catagory3 = "";
}

}
```

Comment: Hint: `foreach( $row as $cat ) { /* code! */ }`

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL and everything to do with not having a very good PHP reference. This looks like code, but it doesn't mean anything. It's the sort of stuff that shows up on screens in CSI when they want to do a "hacking" shot.

Comment: http://www.how-do-you-spell.com/catagory

Comment: Hehehe... Thanks for the spelling help as well.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop.
Try this!

```
$bookCategories = Array("18"=>"Thriller", "19"=>"Fantasy", "20"=>"Science Fiction");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $bookcategory[] = $bookCategories[$category];
}
```

Comment: Elegant answer. This produces one odd effect, though. In the following echo $bookcatagoryX produces a <br>.  Here is the code: `<p><?php echo $bookcatagory1 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory2 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory3 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory4 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory5 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory6 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory7 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory8 ?>&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: Output looks like this (when number are 18, 19, 20). Even though I use &nbsp;

Thriller (carriage return)
Fantasy  (carriage return)
Science Fiction (carriage return)



Is there a <BR> created inside the string?

`<p><?php echo $bookcatagory1 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory2 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory3 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory4 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory5 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory6 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory7 ?>&nbsp;</p><p><?php echo $bookcatagory8 ?>&nbsp;</p>`